# Как скрыть моб меню при клике на ссылку

Tags: html, jquery, menu

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с меню. Нужно что бы при клике на якорное меню (Landing page) в мобилке меню закрывалось.

```
<!-- main-navigation start -->
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="mobile-menu-trigger">
                            <i></i>
                            <i></i>
                            <i></i>
                        </div>
                <div class="main-navigation-item">
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                    )
                );
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </nav>
        <!-- main-navigation end -->
```

---

```
$('.mobile-menu-trigger').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('open');
    });
```

Comment: именно в мобилке или вообще?

Comment: Надо на планшет и мобильную версию.